# How to change a link address on a PDF page using iText5?

Tags: java, itext

I want to change the address of the first link on the page 36 of my PDF file.

I can find and read that link but I'm not able to edit it.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<byte[]> pdfs = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> testfiles = Arrays.asList("test.pdf");
    final String dir = "C:\\hadi\\pdf\\";
    for (final String name : testfiles) {
        final File file = new File(dir + name);
        final Path path = Paths.get(file.toURI());
        try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())) {
            final byte[] data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(istream);
            pdfs.add(data);
            final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(data);
            final PdfDictionary pageDictionary = reader.getPageN(36);
            final PdfArray annotations = pageDictionary.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            if (annotations != null && annotations.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; annotations.size() > i; i++) {
                    final PdfObject annot = annotations.getDirectObject(i);
                    final PdfDictionary annotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(annot);
                    if (annotationDictionary.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).equals(PdfName.LINK)) {
                        final PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotationDictionary.getAsDict(PdfName.A);
                        if (annotationAction.get(PdfName.S).equals(PdfName.URI)) {
                            final PdfString destination = annotationAction.getAsString(PdfName.URI);
                            final String url = destination.toString();
                            System.out.println(url);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            final int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println("Pages : " + n);
            Files.write(Paths.get(dir + "new.pdf"), data);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Preferably I don't want to completely remove that link and create a new one with all the required info (Rectangle, etc.), just removing the link address and putting a new address instead of the previous one.

Comment: `file = new File(name); path = Path.get(file.toURI()); istream = new FIS(path.toFile());` *Why though?!*

Comment: Nearly identical to [this question asked two hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57671367/1729265). You should talk with each other in your company before posting here.

Comment: Even though the duplicated question mentions a different iText version (4 instead of 5), the solution should look the same except for imports.